# Powershell replace value

Tags: powershell, powercli, powershell-7.0

A little help please, i am trying to run the below command against an API. I want to return the fields i care most about i.e. VmName, Vpgname and then create a new column called "StatusText", in this column i am trying to query the value of $_.Status and say if it equals 1 to replace enter or replace the value in said column with "Meeting SLA" if it does not then to say it needs attention essentially.

```
$VMList | select VmName, Vpgname, @{n = 'StatusText'; e={ if ($_.Status -eq "1" {Write-Output "Meeting SLA"} else {Write-Output "Status needs confirming"})}}
```

Comment: You're missing `)` after `if ($_.Status -eq "1"` (or you've moved it too far left, depending on how you perceive it)

Comment: Ah... Sometimes it helps to walk away to grab a coffee.. Or have a new set of eyes. Very helpful thank you

Comment: You may consider not trying to write everything in one long line of code, but separate it after the `|` into multiple lines. Mistakes like that show up better then.